# Função não chega no endpoint - Ionic 3 + API NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic, ionic3

Num app em Ionic 3 tenho essa função validarCupom() que quando é chamada envia um GET pra , caso ela tenha o retorno 200 (OK), então chama a outra função setBonificacaoConveniado().

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo como está a função que precisa ser chamada caso a primeira tenha sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao final, o código que a função setBonificacaoConveniado() deve rodar na API.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No console de debug da aplicação, aparece que o status no validarCupom foi 200, ele faz alterações em campos do banco de dados, tudo funcionando, mas quando chega pra entrar na setBonificacaoConveniado ele estoura esse erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código e não imagens, há um botão no editor de perguntas que delimita o código assim o colore levando em consideração o código em relação as tags.

Comment: O problema pode ser o `res.status(200).send({result})` na linha 602 o node só faz o envio de um response por request e o try logo abaixo possui outra query com response de erro que não poderia ser enviado mesmo se ouve erro, pois, o response já foi chamado.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, você está colocando dois retornos no mesmo método. O TypeError está no console.log().

```
app.post("/teste", function(req, res) {
        var array = [];
        try{
            res.status(200).send(excecao);
            try{
                console.log("teste" + array);
            }catch (e) {
                res.status(200).send(excecao);
            }
        }catch (excecao) {
            res.status(200).send(excecao);
        }
    });
```

Quando ele entra no segundo Try do código, ele cai na Exceção do TypeError e se passar desse TypeError vai entrar no:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Provavelmente é isso que está acontecendo.